# Did jsf <h:datatable> fetch data two times?

Tags: jsf, tags, datatable

I'm using JSF 2.0. I wanted to use h:dataTable and I realized that the function from value in dataTable is invoked 2 times when I open view in browser.

I'm confused with that and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it's normal behaviour(?). Please help.

It will go to **System.out.println("getList");** 2 times. It is right?

**Here is my code.**

**Bean class:**

```
package com.sonicwall.es.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class UserBean {

private List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

public UserBean() {
    list.add("Tom");
    list.add("Andy");
}

public List<String> getList() {
    System.out.println("getList");
    return list;
}

public String getString() {
    System.out.println("getString");
    return "String";
}
```

}

**View**

string:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{userBean.string}" />
```

list:

```
<h:dataTable cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="5"
    value="#{userBean.list}" var="item">
  <h:column>        
    <h:outputText value="#{item}">
    </h:outputText>         
  </h:column>   
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters can be called several times during JSF lifecycle. I think [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times) to a similar question can help you. This [comprehensive tutorial about jsf lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) is also useful.

Comment: Thanks,the link you mentioned is useful!